# Godot - How do you make Player and Enemy bounce when damaged

Tags: game-development, godot

In my game I want it so when either the player or the enemy gets damaged they bounce but i do not know how to do so.

code for player:

```gdscript
extends KinematicBody2D

var speed = 200  # speed in pixels/sec
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var hasDagger = false

func get_input():
    velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    if Input.is_action_pressed('right'):
        velocity.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('left'):
        velocity.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('down'):
        velocity.y += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('up'):
        velocity.y -= 1
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("sprint"):
        speed += 100
    if Input.is_action_just_released("sprint"):
        speed -= 100
    
    # Make sure diagonal movement isn't faster
    velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed

func _physics_process(delta):
    get_input()
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
```

enemy code:

```gdscript
extends KinematicBody2D

var run_speed = 201
var velocity = Vector2.ZERO
var collider = null
var health = 3

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    if collider:
        #print(collider)
        velocity = global_position.direction_to(collider.global_position) * run_speed
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)

func _on_DetectRadius_body_entered(body):
    collider = body

func _on_DetectRadius_body_exited(body):
    collider = null

func _on_hit_box_body_entered(body):
    health -= 1
    
    if health == 0:
        get_tree().change_scene("res://scenes/game over.tscn")
```

the health you see in the enemy script is for the player

the player is a kinematicbody2D with a colilistionshape2D and the enemy is the same as that

Comment: It would help to have the movement script for your player. Also knowing what components (Area, CollisionShape, etc) your player and enemy have would be helpful to know what to work with and what would have to be added to achieve this effect.

Comment: Is it better now

Comment: I don't know how the damage code looks like (is it a collision?) but if you must, you can have an object call `move_and_slide` on the other object.

Comment: oh sorry i have a way of getting damage but its only for the play right now and its on the enemy script

Answer (score 0):

What I'm going to show is not the only way to go about this - *In fact, we should be talking about animations and states* - instead it is just one way to tackle this.

I'll define a variable `target`. I'll leave it without specifying a type, so it is variant. However, I'll have it be `Vector2`. The reason I leave it variant, is so it can be `null`. *If I could, I'd type it as a nullable `Vector2`, but Godot does not support that.*

The idea is to have the `KinematicBody2D` go to the `target` position if it is a `Vector2`. But if it isn't, let the regular movement continue. Something like this:

```
export var speed:float
var velocity := Vector2.ZERO
var target = null

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if target != null:
        velocity = global_position.direction_to(target) * speed
    else:
        # call get_input or whatever
        pass

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
```

I'll add a method for this, it will make things easier:

```
export var speed:float
var velocity := Vector2.ZERO
var target = null

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if not advance_to_target():
        # call get_input or whatever
        pass

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)

func advance_to_target() -> bool:
    if target == null:
        return false

    velocity = global_position.direction_to(target) * speed
    return true
```

Well, we should clear `target` when we reach it, and we should not overshoot. Let us fix that:

```
export var speed:float
var velocity := Vector2.ZERO
var target = null

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if not advance_to_target():
        target = null
        # call get_input or whatever

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)

func advance_to_target() -> bool:
    if target == null:
        return false

    var displacement := target - global_position
    var distance := displacement.length()
    if is_zero_approx(distance):
        return false

    var time := get_physics_process_delta_time()
    var max_speed := distance / time
    var direction := displacement / distance
    velocity = direction * min(speed, max_speed)
    return true
```

Here we are computing `max_speed`, which is the speed at which the KinematicBody2D would have to move to reach the `target` in the current physics frame. Any faster than that, and it would overshoot. So we use `min(speed, max_speed)` to make sure the actual speed is capped at that.

And when the target is reached we would have found that the distance is zero. Well, almost zero. Because of rounding errors we cannot rely on it hitting zero exactly. That is why I use `is_zero_approx(distance)`. This also avoids a division by zero at `displacement / distance`.

---

For the enemy we can co-opt this system to chase the `collider`… Let us refactor to make that easier:

```
export var speed:float
var velocity := Vector2.ZERO
var target = null

var collider = null

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    var target_position = null
    if target != null:
        target_position = target
    elif collider != null:
        target_position = collider.global_position

    if not advance_to(target_position):
        target = null

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)

func advance_to(target_position) -> bool:
    if target_position == null:
        return false

    var displacement := position - global_position
    var distance := displacement.length()
    if is_zero_approx(distance):
        return false

    var time := get_physics_process_delta_time()
    var max_speed := distance / time
    var direction := displacement / distance
    velocity = direction * min(speed, max_speed)
    return true
```

Or we can add `get_input` into it:

```
export var speed:float
var velocity := Vector2.ZERO
var target = null

func _physics_process(_delta:float) -> void:
    if not advance_to(target):
        target = null
        get_input()

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)

func advance_to(target_position) -> bool:
    if target_position == null:
        return false

    var displacement := position - global_position
    var distance := displacement.length()
    if is_zero_approx(distance):
        return false

    var time := get_physics_process_delta_time()
    var max_speed := distance / time
    var direction := displacement / distance
    velocity = direction * min(speed, max_speed)
    return true

func get_input():
    velocity = Vector2.ZERO
    if Input.is_action_pressed('right'):
        velocity.x += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('left'):
        velocity.x -= 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('down'):
        velocity.y += 1
    if Input.is_action_pressed('up'):
        velocity.y -= 1
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("sprint"):
        speed += 100
    if Input.is_action_just_released("sprint"):
        speed -= 100
    
    # Make sure diagonal movement isn't faster
    velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed
```

---

Ah, yes, the damage. We are going to set a `target` when we register the collision. Something like this:

```
export var push_back_distance:float

func _on_hit_box_body_entered(body):
    var direction := global_position.direction_to(body.global_position)
    target = global_position - direction * push_back_distance
    # the rest of the code here
```

That should make the `KinematicBody2D` move away from whatever it collided with.

Comment: when i put in the push back code the game crashes when the player enters the hit box

Comment: @RowanKilroy any errors? logs? is it only on the exported game or also in the editor? is `queue_free` or `yield` involved? Does it go away if you only leave `pass` in the code for `body_entered`? Do you think you can discard code to narrow it down? Does changing checks against `null` with `is_instance_valid` solve it?